# Correct translation of Matlab to Python (CID Distance)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

This is the Matlab code for Complexity Invariance Distance ([Source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220906685_A_Complexity-Invariant_Distance_Measure_for_Time_Series))

Q and C are 1d-arrays with similar length.

```
function d = CID(Q, C)
   CE_Q = sqrt(sum(diff(Q).^2));
   CE_C = sqrt(sum(diff(C).^2));
   d = sqrt(sum((Q - C).^2)) * (max(CE_Q,CE_C)/min(CE_Q,CE_C));
```

This is my pythonic translation:

```
def cid_dist(Q,C):
    import numpy as np
    CE_Q = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff(Q)**2))
    CE_C= np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff(C)**2))
    d = np.sqrt(np.sum((Q - C)**2)) * (np.maximum(CE_Q,CE_C)/np.minimum(CE_Q,CE_C))
    return d
```

Is it correct?

Comment: have you......... tried it?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have Matlab and prefer open source.

Comment: that code would almost work in Octave, so give it a go there.

Comment: It's not generally good practice to put the import inside a function definition like this. Imports go at the top of the script unless there'a a good reason not to. In this case you'll re-import numpy everytime the function is called.

Comment: @SimonN That is true.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it in Octave. Both function return identical results.